# Keeping track of user cookies in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I want to allow visitors of my website to upvote or downvote links but I do not want to have any user accounts.  Is there a way to use a cookie or another way to only allow visitors to vote once on each item in rails?  It is ok if they can delete the cookie.  This does not need to be a super official way.  I just want to prevent simple, constant abuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just create a session and save it to the database. Think of it as anonymous user accounts that don't need username/passwords.